# Проблема бота в телеге

Tags: telegram-bot, telebot, бот, python-telegram-bot

**Выдаёт такую ошибку**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Recs\PycharmProjects\bot\bot.py", line 71, in <module>
    bot.polling(none_stop=True)
  File "C:\Users\Recs\PycharmProjects\bot\venv\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 621, in polling
    self.__threaded_polling(non_stop=non_stop, interval=interval, timeout=timeout, long_polling_timeout=long_polling_timeout,
  File "C:\Users\Recs\PycharmProjects\bot\venv\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 695, in __threaded_polling
    raise e
  File "C:\Users\Recs\PycharmProjects\bot\venv\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 651, in __threaded_polling
    self.worker_pool.raise_exceptions()
  File "C:\Users\Recs\PycharmProjects\bot\venv\lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 147, in raise_exceptions
    raise self.exception_info
  File "C:\Users\Recs\PycharmProjects\bot\venv\lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 93, in run
    task(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Recs\PycharmProjects\bot\bot.py", line 68, in bot_message
    bot.send_message(chat_info[1], message.text)
TypeError: 'bool' object is not subscriptable
```

**Уже перепровел все что можно и bool тоже проверял но может из-за рукожопости что-то упустил**

**Сам бот**

````
import telebot
from telebot import types
from database import Database

db = Database('db.db')
bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.TOKEN)

@bot.message_handler(commands = ['start'])
def start(message):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    item1 = types.KeyboardButton('Поиск собеседника')
    markup.add(item1)

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Привет, {0.first_name}! Добро пожаловать в анонимный чат! Нажми на поиск собеседника.'.format(message.from_user),reply_markup=markup)

@bot.message_handler(commands = ['menu'])
def menu(message):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard = True)
    item1 = types.KeyboardButton('Поиск собеседника')
    markup.add(item1)

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Меню'.format(message.from_user), reply_markup=markup)

@bot.message_handler(commands = ['stop'])
def stop(message):
    chat_info = db.get_active_chat(message.chat.id)
    if chat_info != False:
        db.delete_chat(chat_info[0])
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard = True)
        item1 = types.KeyboardButton('Поиск собеседника')
        markup.add(item1)

        bot.send_message(chat_info[1], 'Собеседник покинул чат', reply_markup = markup)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Вы вышли из чата', reply_markup = markup)
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Вы не начали чат!', reply_markup = markup)

@bot.message_handler(content_types = ['text'])
def bot_message(message):
    if message.chat.type == 'private':
        if message.text == ' Поиск собеседника':
            markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard = True)
            item1 = types.KeyboardButton('Остановить поиск')
            markup.add(item1)

            chat_two = db.get_chat() #Берем собеседника ктороые стоит в очереди первый

            if db.create_chat(message.chat.id, chat_two) == False:
                db.add_queue(message.chat.id)
                bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Поиск собеседника', reply_markup=markup)
            else:
                mess = 'Собеседник найден! Чтобы остановить диалог, нажмите /stop'
                markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
                item1 = types.KeyboardButton('/stop')
                markup.add(item1)

                bot.send_message(message.chat.id, mess, reply_markup=markup)
                bot.send_message(chat_two, mess, reply_markup=markup)


        elif message.text == 'Остановить поиск':
            db.delete_queue(message.chat.id)
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Поиск остановлен, напишите /menu')

        else:
            chat_info = db.get_active_chat(message.chat.id)
            bot.send_message(chat_info[1], message.text)


bot.polling(none_stop=True)```


**База данных**



```import sqlite3

class Database:
    def __init__(self, database_file):
        self.connection = sqlite3.connect(database_file, check_same_thread=False)
        self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()

    def add_queue(self, chat_id):
        with self.connection:
            return self.cursor.execute("INSERT INTO 'queue' ('chat_id') VALUES (?)", (chat_id,))

    def delete_queue(self, chat_id):
        with self.connection:
            return self.cursor.execute("DELETE FROM 'queue' WHERE 'chat_id' = ?", (chat_id,))

    def delete_chat(self, id_chat):
        with self.connection:
            return self.cursor.execute("DELETE FROM 'chats' WHERE 'id' = ?", (id_chat,))

    def get_chat(self):
        with self.connection:
            chat = self.cursor.execute("SELECT FROM 'queue'", ()).fetchmany(1)
            if(bool(len(chat))):
                for row in chat:
                    return row[1]
            else:
                return False

    def create_chat(self, chat_one, chat_two):
        with self.connection:
            if chat_two != 0:
                #создание чата
                self.cursor.execute("DELETE FROM 'queue WHERE' 'chat_id' = ?", (chat_two,))
                self.cursor.execute("INSERT INTO 'chats'('chat_one', 'chat_two') VALUES (?,?)", (chat_one, chat_two,))
                return True

            else:
                return False

    def get_active_chat(self, chat_id):
        with self.connection:
            chat = self.cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM 'chats' WHERE 'chat_one' = ?", (chat_id,))
            id_chat = 0
            for row in chat:
                id_chat = row[0]
                chat_info = [row[0], row[2]]

            if id_chat == 0:
                chat = self.cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM 'chats' WHERE 'chat_two' = ?", (chat_id,))
                for row in chat:
                    id_chat = row[0]
                    chat_info = [row[0], row[1]]
                if id_chat == 0:
                    return False
                else:
                    return chat_info
            else:
                return chat_info```
````

Comment: Ну так а что вы хотите? У вас chat_info является типом данных bool, а вы дальше пытаетесь взять 0-ой элемент `db.delete_chat(chat_info[0])`.

Comment: Так а как это исправить ?)

Comment: Просто я полный чайник только начинаю разбираться

Comment: Что вам должна возвращать `db.get_active_chat(message.chat.id)` ?

Comment: Сама эта функция передачи сообщений между пользователями через бота, db.get_active_chat(message.chat.id)  а должна возвращать id пользователя